# React BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker-compose, react-router

I'm trying to build my application but i get the following error.
As far as i can see it has to do with how i defined the routes but i can't manage to find a solution. The app originally only had one route, and i changed the code to have multiple routes (see the code below).

Do you guys have any clues? Thank you

```
#0 29.92 TS2769: No overload matches this call.
#0 29.92   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps | Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
#0 29.92     Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>'.
#0 29.92   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: BrowserRouterProps, context: any): BrowserRouter', gave the following error.
#0 29.92     Type '{ children: Element; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps>'.
#0 29.92      7 |
#0 29.92      8 | ReactDOM.render(
#0 29.92   >  9 |   <BrowserRouter>
#0 29.92        |    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 29.92     10 |     <App />
#0 29.92     11 |   </BrowserRouter>,
#0 29.92     12 |   document.getElementById("root")
```

App.tsx

```
import { Invitation } from "./components/Invitation";
import { Credential } from "./components/Credential";
import { Home } from "./components/Home";
import { Proof } from "./components/Proof";
// Router
import { Switch, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
      <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/invitation" exact>
          <Invitation />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/credential" exact>
          <Credential />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/proof" exact>
          <Proof />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals(console.log());
```

**EDIT 1**
The issue comes out when i try to build the code using docker-compose. If i run locally `yarn start` for the frontend, no issues. Therefore, here is the dockerfile for the frontend side.

```
FROM node:16.10.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", "./"]

RUN yarn

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

And also of course, the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "animo-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "description": "Animo Solutions - Verifiable Credential Demo",
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^5.9.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.1",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.9",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "qrcode.react": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-confetti": "^6.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
My new app.tsx looks like this after react v6 update:

```
import { Invitation } from "./components/Invitation";
import { Credential } from "./components/Credential";
import { Home } from "./components/Home";
import { Proof } from "./components/Proof";
// Router
import { Switch, Route, useLocation, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/invitation' exact component={Invitation} />
        <Route path="/credential" exact component={Credential} />
        <Route path="/proof" exact component={Proof} />
      </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` is installed? You can check by running `npm list react-router-dom` in the terminal from the root project directory. Can you share also your package.json file?

Comment: It looks like this:└── (empty)

Comment: The issue is only when i try to build the code using dockercompose, not when i run it locally (see Edit 1)

Comment: What version of node are you running locally (*as compared to what is specified in the docker container*)? Node 16.10 *should* be alright.

Comment: That's the thing, the original maintainer of the repo suggested me to use 16.8.0, but when running the docker-compose file, it was required to move to 16.10.

Comment: So are you trying to install and use `react-router-dom@5` or `react-router-dom@6`? When you upgraded to v6 is the issue/error still the same or do you now have different errors or issues, like blank pages?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the local version uses `react-router-dom` v5 and the docker-compose uses v6.
You are still using `<Switch>` and React Router v6 introduces a `<Routes>` component. These versions are not compatible.

More here:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes

I can think of two ways of solving this issue:

1. change your code to match React Router v6
2. ensure that all the compilers use React Router v5

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I was checking on this (see edit 2), but i basically would need to redesign couple of things in there, to make it work. Is there in your opinion any other solution (also dirty-solutions are accepted)

Comment: I edited my answer. If you don't wanna upgrade the code you can try to force v5 with docker-compose. I can't be more specific because I don't use docker-compose, but it seems to be solvable.